# WSO2 API Manager Block fraud requests

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We can currently enable alerting on API: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Alert+Types.

Is it possible also block incoming requests or enforce additional authentication when some conditions had happened?